# What Graphql type will be for Phone Numbers

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

GraphQLInt only supports upto 4,5 integers
GraphQLFloat can't be a phone number,

so what can be used for phone numbers
           `7189008290`

Answer (score 2):

`GraphQLString` is the way to go. Since you're not doing any math operations or whatever, why wouldn't you use it? You can do something like this:

```
fields : () => {
   id: { type: GraphQLId },
   phoneNumber: { type: GraphQLString },
   args: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLId) },
   resolve: (_, obj, args) => ...
}
```

Above is a small example where you're returning a phone number as a string using client id as argument

EDIT:

`GraphQLInt` was't designed for phone numbers, easiest way to do it is with string. Even though you could have used `GraphQLInt`, you still needed some kind of validation..(ex: 000000877, not a valid phone number) . You don't need to do the validation by yourself,  you can always use this package: https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/README.md

Since it's a simple front end validator, the GraphQL performance won't be affected ;)

Comment: if the front-end sends just a string and Int combination for phoneNumber then ????

`71w9ee08u90`

Comment: I don't get it, could you be more explicit? Is your number phone sent as a string converted to something else?

Comment: If I didn't do any kind of validation in front-end then, as `PhoneNumber` type is `GraphQLString` it will simply accept any String. which i don't want to do..